# Why is client disconnecting and reconnecting in node + express + socket.io + jade simple app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

I created a simple application as an attempt to integrate node, express, socket.io, and jade.  The user enters some string ("tool ID") in a text field and clicks a submit button.  That text is simply converted to all uppercase and the result is appended to the results section on the page.  The results should be automatically updated for other clients viewing the page.

It mostly works.  However the problem is that right after the user clicks the submit button on the page to submit the tool ID, the node console and browser javascript console both show the client disconnecting and then reconnecting.

To the user it looks like the results are updated correctly for a fraction of a second.  Then the results go blank for another fraction of a second.  Then the results are redisplayed.  Since I am showing the user's session ID with the results, I can see that the session ID changes during the short time while the results go blank.

Note that if a different client is simply viewing the page, but not otherwise interacting, the results are updated smoothly (no brief time of results going blank) and that client doesn't seem to be disconnecting at all.

I don't want the client to disconnect and reconnect when they click the submit button on the form.  Can someone tell me why this is happening and how I should be doing it properly?

My **app.js** (server)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // without the var, this becomes available to other files like routes.
var path = require('path');
var routes = require('./routes/routes');
var process = require('./routes/process');
var _ = require("underscore");

// all environments
app.set('port', 3097);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
//app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser()); //Tells server to support JSON, urlencoded, and multipart requests
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('i7iir5b76ir857bveklfgf'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var toolIDs = [];

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("Client connected.  Sending Update");

    socket.on("toolsRequest", function() {
        socket.emit('toolsReady', {toolIDs: toolIDs}); //This should go to the client that just connected.
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function() {
        console.log("Client Disconnected");
    });

    socket.on("toolsUpdate", function(data) {
        processedToolID = process.process(data.toolID);
        toolIDs.push({id: data.id, inputToolID: data.toolID, outputToolID: processedToolID}); 
        io.sockets.emit("toolsUpdated", {toolIDs: toolIDs}); //This should go to all clients
        console.log('Results Updated - notifying all clients');
    });
});

// display main page
app.get('/', routes.home);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

My **routes.js**

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.home = function(req, res){
    res.render('home', { title: 'Tool'});
    console.log("Just called route.home");
};
```

My **home.jade**

```
doctype 5
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')
        script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
        script(src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js")
        script(src='/js/index.js')
block content
    #wrapper
    h1 
        a(href='/') TOOL
    #display
        div.row-fluid
            div.inlineBlock
                form#toolForm
                    label Tool ID
                    input(type="text", placeholder="e.g. abc123")#toolID
                    span.help-block You may enter a string.
                    button(class="btn")#submit
                        | Submit
                br
            div.inlineBlock.topAligned
                h2 Results
                br
                div#results
                br
```

My **index.js** (client)

```
function init() {

    /* 
    On client init, try to connect to the socket.IO server.
    */
    var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:3097/');

    //We'll save our session ID in a variable for later
    var sessionID = '';

    //Helper function to update the results  
    function updateResults(toolIDs) {
        $('#results').html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < toolIDs.length; i++) {
            $('#results').append('<span id="' + toolIDs[i].id + '">' + '<b>Creator ID:</b> ' + toolIDs[i].id + ' <b>Your ID:</b> ' + sessionID + ' <b>Input Tool:</b> ' + toolIDs[i].inputToolID + ' <b>Output Tool:</b> ' + toolIDs[i].outputToolID + (toolIDs[i].id === sessionID ? '<b>(You)</b>' : '') + '<br /></span>');
        } 
    }

    /*
    When the client successfully connects to the server, an
    event "connect" is emitted.
    */
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        sessionID = socket.socket.sessionid;
        // Note this appears in the browser Javascript console, not node console
        console.log('You are connected as: ' + sessionID);    
        socket.emit('toolsRequest'); //Request the tools data so we can update results
    });

    socket.on('toolsReady', function(data) {
        updateResults(data.toolIDs);
        console.log('Results have been updated from socket.on.toolsReady');  
    });

    socket.on('toolsUpdated', function (data) {
        updateResults(data.toolIDs);
        console.log('Results updated from socket.on.toolsUpdated');
    });

    /*
    Log an error if unable to connect to server
    */
    socket.on('error', function (reason) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to server', reason);
    });

    function getCitations() {
        var toolID = $('#toolID').val()
        socket.emit('toolsUpdate', {id: sessionID, toolID: toolID});
    }

    $('#submit').on('click', getCitations);
}

$(document).on('ready', init);
```

Here's what I see in the **node console** when a client clicks the submit button:

```
 debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"toolsUpdated","args":[{"toolIDs":[{"id":"5a1dfX2dmxcogYT_11e8","inputToolID":"a123123","outputToolID":"A123123"},{"id":"OIuqao6TsTeddQm111e-","inputToolID":"1abcdefg","outputToolID":"1ABCDEFG"},{"id":"Qr_YQ2ZhQHbDpBlk11e_","inputToolID":"abcdefg","outputToolID":"ABCDEFG"}]}]}
Results Updated - notifying all clients
Just called route.home
   info  - transport end (socket end)
   debug - set close timeout for client Qr_YQ2ZhQHbDpBlk11e_
   debug - cleared close timeout for client Qr_YQ2ZhQHbDpBlk11e_
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client Qr_YQ2ZhQHbDpBlk11e_
Client Disconnected
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 2bPKGgmLdD4fp-vz11fA
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/2bPKGgmLdD4fp-vz11fA
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 2bPKGgmLdD4fp-vz11fA
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
Client connected.  Sending Update
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"toolsReady","args":[{"toolIDs":[{"id":"5a1dfX2dmxcogYT_11e8","inputToolID":"a123123","outputToolID":"A123123"},{"id":"OIuqao6TsTeddQm111e-","inputToolID":"1abcdefg","outputToolID":"1ABCDEFG"},{"id":"Qr_YQ2ZhQHbDpBlk11e_","inputToolID":"abcdefg","outputToolID":"ABCDEFG"}]}]}
```

Thanks, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit button is actually reloading the page, which is why the socket is disconnecting, and why you see the socket response for such a short time. Just prevent the default action of the submit button. Change this:

```
$('#submit').on('click', getCitations);
```

To something similar:

```
$('#submit').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  getCitations();
});
```